# Is it true that if $f$ is surjective from $A$ to $B$ then there is an injective function $g$ from $B$ to $A$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I think the answer is yes because otherwise $f$ wouldn't be a function.
Is this correct? And how would the formal proof go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. To prove it we use the axiom of choice. Since $f$ is surjective then for every element of $b \in B$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $f(a)=b$. To construct the function $g$ we choose one such $a$ for every $b$ and map the $b$ into that $a$ which we know exists. This map is injective by construction.

Comment: and if I am strictly working in (ZF) does this mean we cannot prove the statement?

Comment: @yoloexpectz Yes, if the statement holds, then AC holds. It's equivalent. As I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct but is equivalent to the [Axiom of Choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice) (because we have to pick a unique element from each (non-empty!) $f^{-1}[\{b\}]$, essentially). But AC is widely believed and used, so don't worry.

The proof I sketched above (using AC).